# Crawling data from a div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Good morning, I have little issue when I would like crawle data from a div. For example I have a structure on the website like:

```
<div class="score-result">
Player1Name
Player1Surname
<div>score</div>
</div>
```

I would like to get names, surnames and score of the players. I've written smth like this, but it doesn't print anything.

```
def trade_spider(max_hall,max_period):
    hall=2
    period=1
    while hall <= max_hall:
        url ='https://tabletennis.setkacup.com/en/schedule?date=2021-08-27&hall=' +str(hall)+'&'+'period='+str(period)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text=source_code.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'score-result'}):
            score = link.get('score-result')
            print(score)
            hall=+1
            period=+1
```

Comment: I have checked `plain_text` and there is not table element that have `score-result` class.

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: @Xitiz, I think it is the result of inspect element. But please check it on requests result. It doesn't exist.

Comment: I would like get all information from div class="score-result", also I tried to call this as div but doesn't work.
https://gyazo.com/5d17ddb5960e7339db7d015971890159

Comment: @JimmyFrutado pls post the screenshot of the ```div``` from which you want to get names and scores

Comment: Hello, I know. I also check it on inspect of web browser. But did you check it on requests.get(url) results? On there, it doesn't exist. So, it is not working. I think you have to use selenium for working.

Comment: I didn't check, its my first crawling program and I did everything from similar tutorial. I will read about selenium, thanks for help.

Comment: I will add reference code.

Comment: @lionking-123 I am not sure why you are asking me that question! I don't think that question should be for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code on your side.

```
import requests
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(os.path.abspath('chromedriver'))
service.start()
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.abspath('chromedriver'), options=option)

hall = 2
period = 1
while hall <= 5:
    url = 'https://tabletennis.setkacup.com/en/schedule?date=2021-08-27&hall=' + \
        str(hall)+'&'+'period='+str(period)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.score-result")
    for div in divs:
        # you can add this code
        try :
            fund = div.find_element_by_tag_name("div").text
            print(fund)
        catch :
            pass

        print(div.text)

    hall = hall + 1
```

Hope to be helpful for you.

Comment: I have a little problems with webdriver, but I will try to resolve this problem when I will get to home. Thanks for help anyway friend!
https://gyazo.com/9754c693063c7338c65dd78e5a8d0f83

Comment: If it is helpful for you, please vote me and ticked my answers. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your ticket. I hope to vote up, too. Thanks again.

Comment: Its required to have 15 reputation, as soon as I will reach this number I vote you ;)

Comment: sorry for confusing, but to properly run this code I should only install webdriver? Is it all? And give his path here:  os.path.abspath?

Comment: No, you can download chrome driver and place it on the same directory of python code file. Then, it will run without code changes.

Comment: I have a last question to this issue, 
https://gyazo.com/714b878efaf401f1159edd94f8618e34
I have div score result and under this there is a div with no class. I would like to get data from him to another variable, is it possible? I tried to refer to div $0 but it didn't work :/

Comment: Okay. Then, I will change my answer and you can check it. And hope to vote up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I will reach amount of reputation to vote up you can be sure I do it.